# While loop taking me for a ride (in C)!

Tags: c, cs50

I'm learning computer science by going through Harvard's CS50 course. I'm learning how to define new functions and link two together. I randomly created the script below. My new_function is failing to deliver a false value to the main function, so my 'while' loop is printing like its the wild west. Anything obvious that I'm missing here? thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool new_function(int x1);

int main(void)
{
    int whatever = get_int("get_int now!\n");

    while(new_function(whatever) == true)
    {
        printf("still working\n");
    }
}

bool new_function(int x1)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= x1; i++)
    {
        if(i != 5)
            return true;
        else if (i == 5)
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you input for `whatever`? Also why not just `return x1 != 5;`?

Comment: `new_function` will always return true because the first iteration will already return on `i=1` and therefore `i != 5`

Comment: CS50 has it's own page to answer questions. https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ . You will get easy answer there. Here you will get down voted for easy things  you should be able to figure out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

For the while loop to continue, the condition needs to be true. digging deeper we see
`new_function(whatever) == true` condition. So the result depends intrinsically from
`new_function(int)` you wrote above.

The values that your `new_function(int)` receives as a argument is an integer.
For being such type its domain is whole numbers from somewhere minus 2³¹ to a positive (2³¹ - 1) value, for a 4 byte int.

Next, before the for loop starts it creates a new variable `i` initialized as 1, then it checks if `i` is less or equal than `x1`. If true, it then proceeds, else it ends `for` loop and returns `false`. So from those steps, we see that for a value for `x1` below 1 the `new_function(int x1)` returns false, else  it goes into the loop.

Going further, into the for loop, where case is for `i` from 1 to `x1`, assuming `x1` is equal or greater than 1, there is a conditional checking `if (i != 5)`, being `i` always initialized as 1, so different than 5, it always execute `return true`, and the else part isn't reached.

So resuming, as long as you give a number greater than 0, your code will print  like wild west. :)